# В App Designer создала таблицу. Как можно сохранить таблицу в формате .txt

Tags: matlab

В App Designer создала таблицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо при нажатии кнопки данные таблицы сохранились в файл формата .txt. Как это можно осуществить?

Только начала изучать App Designer. Опыта в программировании не имею. Документация Matlab не помогла.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого сперва вам нужно в AppDesigner найти свою кнопку в списке, и в контекстном меню выбрать callback функцию. Тогда во вкладке с кодом появится новая запись с пустой функцией. Именно туда и требуется вписать саму функцию, которая будет выглядеть примерно как
writematrix(table1.value, '1.txt')
Единственная загвоздка может возникнуть в том, что в большинстве случаев переменная .value для различных заполняемых форм представляет собой cell-массив, который не всегда можно записать. Поэтому нужно будет проверить, что извлекается именно строковое значение, если нет, то string(table1.value).